# a true index---multiple matching in perl

Tags: string, perl

let's say I have a keyword file, that contains, say "ab", "ef", "ab ef" (real life: another thousand entries).  I want to look up on what pages each of my keywords are occurring

```
page 0
ab
gg
^L
page 1
ab ef
^L
page 2
Ab
ef
[another thousand pages, 2 million words, each ^L separated]
```

I want to get back

```
ab => [ 0,1,2 ]
ef => [ 1,2 ]
ab ef => [ 1 ]
```

I know how to do this very inefficiently.  slurp the file into a long string.  lowercase it.  split it into pages.  for each page, regex each (lowercased) keyword entry to see if it appears on the page.  if so, then add the page number at the end of a hash that contains my keyword as key.  not hard, but painfully inefficient.  my algorithm seems more like a C approach rather than an elegant perl approach.

alas, I can't think of a better alternative.  I cannot even read the main file into a hash first, because the possibility of space-separated multi-word keywords would make this inelegant bad logic.

maybe perl is the wrong tool for this?!

Answer (score 4):

The other answers employ unneccessary complicated means. Key to this problem is understanding that we can set the line ending `$/` to whatever we like. `^L` represents the form feed `\f`.

```
use strict; use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils qw/uniq/;

my %keywords;
local $/ = "\f";  # set the input record separator (aka. line end) to form feed

while (<>) {
  chomp; # remove the \f
  my ($page, $body) = split /\n/, $_, 2;    # seperate the page header
  my $page_no = ($page =~ /([0-9]+)/) ? $1  # extract the page number
                : die "Header did not contain a number:\n$page\n";

  # split body into lines, and lines into words. Keep only unique KWs:
  my @words = uniq map { $_, split } split /\n/, lc $body;
  # Map KWs to an array of page №s.
  push @{ $keywords{$_} }, $page_no for @words;
}

# Output the data:
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%keywords;
```

Comment: I don't think it solves the problem.  it converts a file into its constituent words, and assigns a page number to each word.

Comment: I don't think it solves the problem.  it converts a file into its constituent words, and assigns a page number to each word.  it does not start from a list of words that can include phrases that can include spaces.  wouldn't it be quicker to do

    my \@page = split(/f/, slurp($filename));
    for my $pageno (0..$#page) {
        my \@wordsonpage = split /[\n\s]/, $page[$pageno];
        push @{ words{$_} }, $pageno for \@wordsonpage
    }
    # and now we have a hash of words with page numbers

Comment: @ivoWelch The solution you sketched out does not produce the expected output in your question, as `ab ef` key would be missing (neither do these answers: they add the `gg` entry). If my answer does not solve the problem, could you clarify what the exact requirements are, and maybe update your test case to reflect that?

Answer (score 1):

This is perfect for Perl; just look at it the other way around.  With each keyword, add the current page to that word's page list.  Create the word's page list if it's the first we've seen.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;


my %keywords = ();
my $page = 0;

while (<>)
{
    chomp;  # remove newline

    if (/^page \d+$/)   # skip "page 0", etc.
    {
        next;
    }
    elsif (/^\l$/)      # ctrl-L: new page
    {
        ++$page;
    }
    else
    {
        my $word = lc($_);

        addWord($word);

        if ($word =~ /\s/)
        {
            my @parts = split(/\s+/, $word);

            for my $part (@parts)
            {
                addWord($part);
            }
        }
    }
}

print Dumper(%keywords);


sub addWord
{
    my ($word) = @_;

    # haven't seen this word? start an empty page list
    if (! defined($keywords{$word}))
    {
        $keywords{$word} = [];
    }

    # add current page to the word's list
    push @{ $keywords{$word} }, $page;
}
```

prints:

```
$VAR1 = 'ef';
$VAR2 = [
          1,
          2
        ];
$VAR3 = 'gg';
$VAR4 = [
          0
        ];
$VAR5 = 'ab';
$VAR6 = [
          0,
          1,
          2
        ];
$VAR7 = 'ab ef';
$VAR8 = [
          1
        ];
```

based on your sample.

Answer (score 1):

Perfect use for perl.

Outputs the following:

```
ab => [ 0,1,2 ]
ab ef => [ 1 ]
ef => [ 1,2 ]
gg => [ 0 ]
```

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

main();
1;

sub main {
    my $data = {};
    my $page = 0;
    while (<DATA>) {
        chomp;
        next if /\A\^L/;
        if (/\Apage (\d+)/) {
            $page = $1;
        } else {
            my $line = lc($_);
            $data->{$line}->{$page}++;
            for (split /\s/, $line) {
                $data->{$_}->{$page}++;
            }
        }
    }

    for my $keyword (sort keys %$data) {
        my @pages = sort {$a <=> $b} keys %{$data->{$keyword}};
        print $keyword . ' => [ ' . join(',',@pages) . ' ]' . "\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
page 0
ab
gg
^L
page 1
ab ef
^L
page 2
Ab
ef
```